# Safe combination of characters for str_replace?

Tags: php, html

What are some safe terms to use for general `str_replace()` use? I have a page that sends an e-mail to a given e-mail address which may or may not contain HTML elements within.

```
$message = "";
$message .= "first line of e-mail<br/>";
$message .= "second line of e-mail<br/>";
$message .= "@w <br/>"; //sample term for str_replace()
$message .= "fourth line of e-mail";
```

The third line is `@w`, or what I plan to replace with a table created using a previous `foreach()` loop `$table`.

```
$newmessage = str_replace("@w",$table,$message);
```

I know this works, I'm just not sure if `@w` or any other arbitrary combination of keys if "safe" to use. The purpose of doing this is because I have a separate page that can edit the `$message` text, and I'd like to just type `@w` or another arbitrary bit to "inject" dynamically created content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace()` works with plain text, so everything is safe to use (though I think it would frown upon empty string or a NULL).

It is `preg_replace()` where you must be careful, for it uses regex to find the matches.